Gradle task on Windows has WSL config issue with relevant paths
On a Windows box, I have a bash script called paths.sh that lists a Java file in the JAVA_HOME directory
#!/bin/bash

echo "Current working directory: $(pwd)"
echo "JAVA_HOME: $JAVA_HOME"
echo "Accessing path: $JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
ls -l "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" || echo "Failed to access java"

When I run it in Git bash directly, it works fine and I get:
$ ./src/test/java/javaToJs/paths.sh
Current working directory: /g/ws/ws-shared
JAVA_HOME: /g/Java/jdk21
Accessing path: /g/Java/jdk21/bin/java
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Admin 197608 54384 Sep 26  2023 /g/Java/jdk21/bin/java

In my build.gradle I have a gradle task to autorun the script on builds
task paths(type: Exec) {
    workingDir 'G:/WS/ws-shared'
    commandLine 'bash', './src/test/java/javaToJs/paths.sh'
}

This doesn't work. It's added a /mnt to the directory path (according to the AI this is due to the Windows Subsystem for Linux) and can't find the Java file to list
$ gradle paths

> Task :paths
Current working directory: /mnt/g/WS/ws-shared
JAVA_HOME: /mnt/g/Java/jdk21
Accessing path: /mnt/g/Java/jdk21/bin/java
ls: cannot access '/mnt/g/Java/jdk21/bin/java': No such file or directory
Failed to access java

I've tried any number of mutations & permutations in this simple process including removing the /mnt from the JAVA_HOME. I get the same issue every time. For example without the /mnt
ls: cannot access '/g/java/jdk21/bin/java': No such file or directory

How is the gradle task adding a /mnt and losing access to a given directory ?
UPDATE: The plot thickens after I uninstalled my Windows subsystem for Linux and restarted. Now when I run the gradle task I get:
$ gradle paths
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 4 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Task :paths FAILED
Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.

Use 'wsl.exe --list --online' to list available distributions
and 'wsl.exe --install <Distro>' to install.

Distributions can also be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store:
https://aka.ms/wslstore
Error code: Bash/Service/CreateInstance/GetDefaultDistro/WSL_E_DEFAULT_DISTRO_NOT_FOUND

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


The bash command via gradle is using WSL. Like this post I had to reinitialise the WSL2 layer, open PowerShell as administrator into my WSL and install a JVM for it.
sudo apt install openjdk-21-jdk
Now I can find the JAVA_HOME path with
readlink -f $(which java)
and set it with
JAVA_HOME=$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink -f $(which java))))
If I set that as my JAVA_HOME then I can run the bash command in my gradle task
NOTE: That means I could not get my local Windows JVM to be used by WSL bash.
Finally, to fix the issue that gradle 'bash' appears to use WSL if it's available, I had to change my build.gradle to use a specific bash instance:
commandLine 'D:\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe', '-c', `paths.sh`


This has fixed the "find a JVM" issue but now I have a whole load more path issues with gradle bash invoking WSL.
